# How to make gdb print symbols in shared libraries loaded with dlopen?

Tags: linux, gdb, shared-libraries

I want to debug a process running on Linux 2.6 using GDB. `attach PID` (where PID is the process ID), `print main`, `print sin`, `print gzopen` and `print dlopen` work (i.e. they find the respective symbols). But `print myfoo` doesn't work, where `myfoo` is a function loaded by the process from an `.so` file using `dlopen`. Here is what I get:

```
(gdb) print main
$3 = {int (int, char **)} 0x805ba90 <main>
(gdb) print sin
$4 = {<text variable, no debug info>} 0xb7701230 <sin>
(gdb) print gzopen
$5 = {<text variable, no debug info>} 0xb720df50 <gzopen>
(gdb) print dlopen
$6 = {<text variable, no debug info>} 0xb77248e0 <__dlopen_nocheck>
(gdb) print myfoo
No symbol "myfoo" in current context.
```

How do I get GDB to find `myfoo`?

The function `myfoo` does indeed exist, because in the program I managed to get its address using `dlsym` (after `dlopen`), and I managed to call it. Only after that I attached GDB to the process.

It turned out that there was a `mydir/mylib.so: No such file or directory` error message printed by the `attach $PID` command of GDB. Apparently GDB was started in the wrong directory. Doing the proper `cd` before starting GDB fixed the problem, and `print myfoo` started working.

I'd like to automate this: I want GDB figure out where my `.so` files (loaded with `dlopen`) are. An approximation I can think of is examining `/proc/$PID/maps` (on Linux), finding possible directories, and adding all of them to the GDB library search path before starting GDB. Extending `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and doing a `set solib-search-path /tmp/parent` didn't work (`ls -l /tmp/parent/mydir/myfoo.so` does work), GDB still reported the `No such file or directory`. How do I tell GDB where to look for `mydir/myfoo.so`?

My other question is how do I get the list of possible directories? On Linux, `/proc/$PID/maps` contains them -- but what about other operating systems like FreeBSD and the Mac OS X?

Comment: Works fine for me.  Post some code.  What flags are you passing to `dlopen`?

Comment: Hmm, browsing through the GDB error messages when attaching, I have found `mylib.so: No such file or directory`. After doing the proper `cd` before starting GDB, `print myfoo` started working. But I'd like to automate that (so `cd` is not required). I've expanded the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is no easy way to automate finding finding `.so` files in GDB.

Answer (score 5):

"info target" command in gdb will show a list of all sections in all loaded shared objects (including dlopen()ed libraries). At least this works on Linux -- I don't know how it behaves on other operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

I maintain a program that loads a shared library via dlopen() and have successfully accessed symbols in the shared library using GDB.  This will only work, however, if the shared library has a symbol table.

Comment: Yes, it works for me too if I start GDB from the right directory. I've expanded the question about automating that.